# Sharing buildout-cache/eggs across several UNIX users

Tags: plone, zope, buildout

On a server there are several independent Plone buildout installations, running under different UNIX accounts.

Is there any reliable mean to share buildout-cache folder on this server across all these different UNIX users? As one Plone eggs/ installation is 250 - 500 MB this would be a small win.

- All UNIX users accessing the shared folder would still be able to run buildout, which adds in new eggs
- New eggs would be available on the disk to other users, without need to re-pull, copy them around
- The users are trusted; there is no fear them going to eggs/ and corrupting for other users

Currently the issue is that eggs/ pulled in by buildout of one UNIX users becomes not writeable by another.

My guess is that there could be some custom sudo script fixing eggs rights after each buildout run.

Any other suggested method for egg sharing?

Comment: I'd be wary of conflicts; two buildouts installing the same egg, corrupting the resulting setup. It may work, and then again, it may not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share all your eggs by putting them in a single directory, as you said, and you can then resolve the permission issue by adding this at your buildouts:

```
[buildout]
parts +=
   chmod

[chmod]
recipe = plone.recipe.command
command =
    chmod -R ugo+rw ${buildout:eggs-directory}
```

Comment: The ugo+rw gives everyone write access, not just the trusted users. Perhaps a "chown/chgrp" with ug+rw perms is better? And, if you don't want the chmod part in each and every buildout, you can also run a similar cronjob every minute.

Comment: +1 for the ug+rw part...I assumed that only trusted user have access to a server, but security in never too much. -1 for the cronjob...because 1) if the eggs directory grows, as it is supposed to do, it'd overload the server and 2) if someone else runs a buildout you have to wait 1 entire minute before you can rerun your instance?! no way, I'd go crazy :P

Answer (score 2):

We use [collective.hostout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.hostout) for all production deployments esp where each install is owned by a different user. Hostout creates a shared group for the global eggs cache. It ensures any egg is group readable after buildout is run.

Comment: And I use hostout, too, but I can see Mikko's problem applying on a development server.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs to me that another solution (not as good as the chmod recipe, imo, but maybe somebody will see some value) is to only share the download-cache - now other users will still not need to "re-pull" but keep their own eggs directory.  The files in the download cache aren't writable by other users either, but who would be writing to them?  [but then I'm not sure why we care that the eggs are writable, either - who is writing to egg directories?]

Comment: If you get zope to compile .mo files it writes to the egg file... unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @djay, that would certainly cause issues